# how to use VMware vSphere Hypervisor (ESXi) 5 in Q9550

Tags: virtual-machine, esxi, intel-core2, hypervisor

Anybody ever tried VMware vSphere Hypervisor (ESXi) 5.0 in Q9550 ?

Because I'm about to. My PC Spec are :

```
Intel Q9550
J&W motherboard JW-IG41M-HD3 with Intel G41 DDR3 at http://www.jwele.com/motherboard_detail.php?808
8GB DDR3 RAM
1x WDC Blue 320GB 16mb cache
2x 2TB Seagate Baracuda
```

How to run VMware vSphere Hypervisor (ESXi) 5.0 within my PC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem. Just make sure you have Virtualization Technology and related settings ENABLED in your motherboard's BIOS.

Comment: what about the driver ? does VMWare vSphere Hypervisor esxi 5 supports my PC specs ?

Comment: Nobody can definitively answer that for you. Why don't you read in the system requirements and see if any of your components are explicitly stated as "NOT" being supported. Otherwise as I said, it "shouldn't" be a problem.

Comment: I mean... does anybody ever tried it on Q9550 ?

Comment: It WILL work on the Q9550. The Intel ARK docs show clearly that the Q9550 has support for both VT-d and VT-x. http://ark.intel.com/products/33924/Intel-Core2-Quad-Processor-Q9550-(12M-Cache-2_83-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB)